# How do I fix an m4a file that that has no sound beyond the 1st minute?

Tags: sound, aac-m4a, fix, missing

Now sure how these files got corrupted, they were recorded using the default Android Sound Recorder app. There is no sound beyond the first minute but the file is large showing there is info recorded so it isn't like it was blanked or no sound was received by the micro...

Comment: tried importing them into a DAW?

Comment: If it's not just a player anomaly, then you are really up a creek without a paddle unfortunately. Not a lot you can do with encoded files that end up corrupt.

Comment: Tried Audacity...the graph that shows he spectrum is really flat after that first minute :-(

Comment: ...then you're probably done mate. Sorry about that.